# Why my AVX2 horizontal addition function is not faster than non-SIMD addition?

Tags: x86, simd, intrinsics, avx2

I implemented an inline function for adding all elements of a vector, but it's not faster than non-SIMD addition.

Declarations :

```
#define N 128
#define M N
int __attribute__(( aligned(32)))temp8[8];
__m256i vec;
int __attribute__(( aligned(32))) c_result[N][M];
```

These are my two ways for adding all int value in a vector:

First, non-SIMD version is:

```
  _mm256_store_si256((__m256i *)&temp8[0] , vec);
  c_result[i][j]= temp8[0]+temp8[1]+temp8[2]+temp8[3]+temp8[4]+temp8[5]+temp8[6]+temp8[7];
```

Second, AVX2 version:

```
  c_result[i][j] =_mm256_hadd2_epi32(vec);
```

I implemented the hadd2 in this way:

```
// my horizontal addition of epi32
  inline int _mm256_hadd2_epi32(__m256i a)
  {
    __m256i a_hi;
    a_hi = _mm256_permute2x128_si256(a, a, 1); //maybe 1 should be 4 
    a = _mm256_hadd_epi32(a, a_hi);
    a = _mm256_hadd_epi32(a, a);
    a = _mm256_hadd_epi32(a, a);
    return _mm256_extract_epi32(a,0);
  }
```

I use `gcc` , `Linux-mint` , `skylake` microarchitecture.

I guessed it might be because of the following reasons:
There are 4 `ALU` for integers in skylake microarchitecture that will add them fastly in contrast to restricted vector execution units particularly for permutation that needs at least one cycle to reorder the elements followed by some `hadd`instructions. The question is, am I missing something or it's not necessary to use SIMD for adding all elements?

**UPDATE:** I just added the MUL program to the repository [here](https://github.com/sinusee/Intel-SIMD-Technologies/tree/MUL) you can access the whole codes of matrix multiplication. if I use the non-SIMD version elapsed time would be 201 ns and with SIMD version I takes 210 ns.

Comment: Let's take a step back and ask *why* you need to be doing horizontal operations like this, and if you really need to then are they really part of a performance-critical bottleneck ? Typically you should only need to do horizontal operations after a loop, e.g. as the final step of a reduction, which is not usually the important part, performance-wise.

Comment: @PaulR, you are right. it's not for a bottleneck section in this way. And I just wanted to test the performance of `non-SIMD` and `AVX2` version for myself and of course, it's for researching and educational purpose. But the answer will help me. Because I implemented a Convolution Matrix Kernel that 3,5,7 and 9 adjacent elements should be added horizontally in the bottleneck section.

Comment: Optimisation is a bit more complex than that. See the x86 tag wiki for the links to the Agner Fog manuals. You need to consider the front-end, the uops generated, the ports, the latencies7throughputs and the dependency chains.  Have you profiled the code with *perf*?

Comment: @MargaretBloom, I ordinally use the Anger Fog manuals, Intel optimization manuals, `perf`, `IACA`, `Valgrind` etc.  and surely will use for this optimization. But, sometimes a professional mentions a point because of his/her experience that can not be found easily in tools and manuals. As many times Paul and another user Peter helped me in stack and opened a new path in my brain.

Comment: It sounds like you may be approaching 2D convolution the wrong way -  normally you would not do horizontal operations, but instead you shift vector pairs left/right (or use unaligned loads to do the same thing) and then do purely vertical operations.

Comment: It would be interesting to see your code - maybe you could post a new question asking for ideas for further improvements on what you have already ?

Comment: @PaulR, after publication I will add my codes [here](https://github.com/sinusee/Intel-SIMD-Technologies)

Comment: After publishing these codes, I will publish my main paper, but all codes would be available there. BWT because of my poor English skill, It takes too much time for me. But the point is I found some new approach that would be interesting to know about it . and after that, I want to use them for building a new programming model particularly for Intel microarchitecture for educational purposes

Comment: OK - good luck with that then - I look forward to studying it when you finally publish.

Comment: Can you post an [mcve]? Something that I can benchmark and play with? I don't know what `temp8` and `vec` are.

Comment: @CodyGray, I just added the MUL program to the repository [here](https://github.com/sinusee/Intel-SIMD-Technologies/tree/MUL) you can access the whole codes of matrix multiplication

Comment: But I didn't comment codes appropriately or clarify them you. However, you can play with that. I will do later

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The intuition might be that this step...

```
temp8[0]+temp8[1]+temp8[2]+temp8[3]+temp8[4]+temp8[5]+temp8[6]+temp8[7]
```

is the expensive part that vectorization should accelerate, but it is probably wrong. Addition is a single muop, and you can execute 4 per cycle on a recent x64 machine as long as you work over registers (not memory). So, in theory, your processor can do this...

cycle 1.

```
temp8[0]+temp8[1]
temp8[2]+temp8[3]
temp8[4]+temp8[5]
temp8[6]+temp8[7]
```

cycle 2

```
(temp8[0]+temp8[1])+(temp8[2]+temp8[3]) 
(temp8[4]+temp8[5])+(temp8[6]+temp8[7])
```

and get the answer on cycle 3, with capacity to spare. (Our processors are superscalar and have an out-of-order pipeline so this will happen magically.)

How much faster can a vectorized approach be? You gave us the answer...

```
a = _mm256_hadd_epi32(a, a_hi);
a = _mm256_hadd_epi32(a, a);
a = _mm256_hadd_epi32(a, a);
```

We can recognize the 3 cycles...  Of course, it looks cheaper, maybe... but what is probably underneath the `_mm256_hadd_epi32` intrinsic is the `PHADD` instruction (~3 muops, 1 instruction every two cycles). The important point is that the processor cannot execute several of the `_mm256_hadd_epi32` intrinsics simultaneously while it can do several of the scalar additions simultaneously. Thus, you see, which is faster becomes a technical matter.

Anyhow, to sum up my answer... You should not expect vectorization to help in this instance (at least not help a lot) because it is going against superscalar execution of cheap instructions (add).

Appendix.  This code

```
  _mm256_store_si256((__m256i *)&temp8[0] , vec);
  c_result[i][j]= temp8[0]+temp8[1]+temp8[2]+temp8[3]+temp8[4]+temp8[5]+temp8[6]+temp8[7];
```

probably does not get compiled to what you think. Let us flush it out as a function

```
uint32_t hadd32(__m256i vector) {
  uint32_t buffer[sizeof(__m256i)/sizeof(uint32_t)];
 _mm256_store_si256((__m256i *)buffer , vector);
 uint32_t answer = buffer[0]+buffer[1]+buffer[2]+buffer[3]+buffer[4]+buffer[5]+buffer[6]+buffer[7];
 return answer;
}
```

Several compilers (clang, GCC 7), compile this down to

```
    vpextrd edx, xmm0, 1
    vmovd   eax, xmm0
    add     eax, edx
    vpextrd edx, xmm0, 2
    add     eax, edx
    vpextrd edx, xmm0, 3
    vextracti128    xmm0, ymm0, 0x1
    add     eax, edx
    vmovd   edx, xmm0
    add     eax, edx
    vpextrd edx, xmm0, 1
    add     eax, edx
    vpextrd edx, xmm0, 2
    add     eax, edx
    vpextrd edx, xmm0, 3
    add     eax, edx
```

where we recognize the additions, but where the temporary buffer as been ignored entirely in favor of `vpextrd` calls. The lesson here is to always look at the generated assembly.